# White shade appears on my Dell Inspiron while watching movies

Tags: laptop, video, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron, while watching movies on full screen a white shade appears frequently.

[image]

It disappears when the lid is closed and opened. While watching online YouTube videos in normal window pane it happens very rarely, when i maximize to full screen it happens frequently. Same goes with any video. It started a month ago now it is a pain. It happens frequently, every now and then i have to close the LCD lid and open it.

Specifications:

- Core i5 M430 @2.27 Ghz
- 4GB RAM
- Intel HD Graphics
- Windows 7 Ultimate, 64-bit Service Pack 1

Comment: Can you make a photo of this phenomena and upload it somewhere so we can see (and then add the photo to your question)?

Comment: @LPChip: pic attached for your reference.